# Relation between spline and $C^d$ curve

Tags: smooth-manifolds, spline

Spline including NURBS, B-spline, etc can provide the $C^d$ continuous curve, which d is based on the degree of the spline. However, can all $C^{d-1}$ continuous curve be expressed by d degree Spline? Thank you very much.

Comment: NURBS and B-spline are not smooth but merely $C^{d-1}$ where $d$ is the spline degree.

Comment: @Coolwater Thanks, I will edit my question based on the information you provide.